# Dissociation of different compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, acid-base, everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution

What would be the dissociation of Hydrosulfuric acid in the presence of water?

I was thinking that Hydrosulfuric acid or $\ce{H2S}_{(aq)}$ would form $\ce{2 H+}$ and Sulfur ions.

With this logic, I keep getting the wrong answer :(

The right answer of this question is it would not dissociate at all.

Shall appreciate some help on explaining this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[$\ce{H2S}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide) has a mostly covalent character. You can decide for it by the crude way textbooks give: Calculate the difference in electronegativity to decide whether it's a non-polar covalent compound, a polar one or has ionic characters.

For the dissociation part (which is usually endothermic overall) it'll need more "ionic character". And it *does* dissociate in water, resulting in a weak acid named  sulfhydric acid. (The spelling varies with citable sources) Your textbook likes to think about it as not dissociable, only because it's a **weak acid**.

### Addendum:

The "ionic character" plays its role of a rule a good one as explaining acid 'strength'. However, it acts almost flawlessly in the same period, but has exceptions when it gets to groups. As Dave mentions, $\ce{HF}$ is weaker than for instance, $\ce{HCl}$ and that's because **the atomic radius changes more dramatically than electronegativity difference**. (See [here](http://drholly.typepad.com/ask_me_a_chemistry_questi/2005/12/why_isnt_hf_a_s.html) ) But, in the $\ce{H2S}$ molecule, this exception hasn't occurred. Dave pointed out a good example of when the rule isn't working that well, but as I said, we can ignore the other factors in this very case.

Comment: so all weak acids do not dissociate?

Comment: No, but "weak acids", as the name fully suggests, dissociate partially. At times, lesser than 1% of the acid dissociates in water, so it's better to think they don't dissociate at all. It's like "Don't bother me with details".

Comment: verry helpful mannnn

Comment: @MARamezani I don't think what your are saying about ionic character and strong versus weak acids is accurate.  The series HF, HCl, HBr and HI has respective ionic charaters of 45%, 17%, 12% and 5%, and HF is a weak acid while the others are strong.

Comment: @DavePhD I'll edit my answer to cover your part.